# $addtoset and append to end

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I love the $addtoset option on MongoDB where you can add to an array of documents if the object doesn't already exist.

But in case, it exists, can I force it to go to the end of the array?

That is.

in this array:

```
[document1,document2,document3]
```

I would like to be able to do $addtoset:document2

```
[document1,document3,document2]
```

Is that something MongoDB supports?